# Meteor 1.4 - General approach to file system + /public activity

Tags: mongodb, meteor, filesystems

I've done some digging around and a lot of the threads regarding file system and how it works with Meteor seem to be pretty outdated, not to mention packages related to file storage/serving (i.e. CollectionFS). I was wondering if anyone here has deep experience with handling files in lieu of 1.4 or even 1.3 (I am currently on 1.4.1.1).

My questions are as follows:

1. Did Meteor 1.3/1.4 come with any changes regarding fs?
2. What is the general best approach to storing and serving static assets in light of Meteor 1.4?
3. I've seen many threads that say dynamically storing files to /public triggers a server upload, but I've tested this on local by manually copy/pasting a .png file into /public, and it only triggers a client refresh with the console message Client modified -- refreshing. Would this hold true for files added during runtime, and would it hold true in production?

Currently I am trying to stay clear from S3 or any other third party CDN's to keep a low budget, and also trying to stay clear from storing files into Mongo.

Thanks for any and all opinions!

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up a shared folder or NFS folder, have your Meteor app handle the file upload, write the file to that location, and configure Nginx or whatever you are using as the load balancer to serve those files.  If you worry about browser refreshed when the file is put into the public folder, you do not need to write files to the public folder right?